# Python3 ZipFile how to write non-utf8 filename to archive by using writestr function

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, zip, gbk

I am writing something like auto-compress files and upload to server, and I'm using `writestr` to directly write bytes to `ZipFile` from memory. But for historical problems, I need to make it display properly on some Windows PC with `GBK` encoding.

Python3's `str` encoding is default `utf-8`. I want to know how to write the correct byte stream for the filename, the content can work with `utf-8` so no need to care file content.

I need a code sample. Thanks. Any solution is acceptable like new a class inherit it.

Comment: The [`zipfile` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) includes this note: *"The ZIP file standard historically did not specify a metadata encoding, but strongly recommended CP437 (the original IBM PC encoding) for interoperability. Recent versions allow use of UTF-8 (only). In this module, UTF-8 will automatically be used to write the member names if they contain any non-ASCII characters. It is not possible to write member names in any encoding other than ASCII or UTF-8."* Maybe explore third-party modules with a different feature set.

Comment: The [`_encodeFilenameFlags` method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/be7c19723fa3fea3a4efe5c9c795c1e4a2fc05f5/Lib/zipfile.py#L481) looks like it could be overridden by one which uses a different encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee).

Override [`_encodeFilenameFlags`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/be7c19723fa3fea3a4efe5c9c795c1e4a2fc05f5/Lib/zipfile.py#L481) method works:

```py
class GBKZipInfo(zipfile.ZipInfo):
    # override _encodeFilenameFlags method, change encoding to GBK
    def _encodeFilenameFlags(self):
        try:
            return self.filename.encode('gbk'), self.flag_bits
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            return self.filename.encode('utf-8'), self.flag_bits | 0x800
```